# Prove tautology by using boolean laws $\neg q \to \neg(q\wedge(p\to\neg q))$

Tags: logic, relations

$$\neg q \to \neg(q\wedge(p\to\neg q))$$

Please help me to prove if it's tautology or not by using the logic law.

Comment: What is "the logic law?"

Comment: Do a four-line truth table covering all possibilities of p being T or F and q being T or F, and see if all choices end up making the expression true.

Comment: they needed by the logic law not truth table :(

Comment: Please, fix your grammar..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using $p\to q = \neg p \vee q $ and distributive laws,
$$\neg{q} \to \neg(q\wedge(p\to \neg q))$$
$$=\neg q \to \neg (q\wedge(\neg p \vee \neg q))$$
$$=\neg q \to \neg ((q\wedge\neg p)\vee(q\wedge\neg q))$$
$$=\neg q \to \neg((q\wedge \neg p)\vee \mathrm{False})$$
$$=\neg q \to \neg(q\wedge\neg p)$$
$$=\neg q \to (\neg q \vee p)$$
$$=q\vee(\neg q \vee p)$$
$$=(q\vee\neg q)\vee(q\vee p)$$
$$=\mathrm(True)\vee(q\vee p)$$
$$=\mathrm{True}$$

Comment: AM so Glad really thanks ..

Answer (score 0):

Using DeMorgan's law on the conclusion, we see that it becomes $\neg q \lor \neg(p\to q)$.

Since $\neg q \to \neg q$, then surely $\neg q \to (\neg q \lor A),$ where $A$ is any propositional statement.

So your statement is a tautology, since it's always true.